# python single test get different result on any runs

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to convert SQL's result to hierarcical dict. I create class DictMaker and write single test. But test's run is fail or
success in sometime. I dont't undestand this behavior. No random's calls in class.

```py
class DictMaker:
    def __init__( self, input_ ):
        self._input = input_
        self._dict = { }

    def dict( self ):
        self._make()
        return self._dict

    def _make( self ):
        for item in self._input:
            for long_key, val in item.items():
                self._add_leaf_value( long_key, val )

    def _add_leaf_value( self, long_key, val ):
        last = self._get_last_item( long_key )
        leaf = self._get_leaf_key( long_key )
        if leaf in last:
            if last[ leaf ] != val:
                list_ = self._get_last_list( long_key )
                key = self._get_leaf_key( long_key )
                list_.append( { key: val } )
        else:
            last[ leaf ] = val

    def _get_leaf_key( self, long_key ):
        return long_key.split( '.' )[ -1 ]

    def _get_last_item( self, long_key ):
        keys = long_key.split( '.' )[ :-1 ]
        parent_dict = self._dict
        parent_list = None
        for key in keys:
            if key in parent_dict:
                parent_list = parent_dict[ key ]
                parent_dict = parent_list[ -1 ]
            else:
                sub_dict = { }
                parent_list = [ sub_dict ]
                parent_dict[ key ] = parent_list
                parent_dict = sub_dict

        return parent_list[ -1 ]

    def _get_last_list( self, long_key ):
        keys = long_key.split( '.' )[ :-1 ]
        parent_dict = self._dict
        parent_list = None
        for key in keys:
            if key in parent_dict:
                parent_list = parent_dict[ key ]
                parent_dict = parent_list[ -1 ]
            else:
                sub_dict = { }
                parent_list = [ sub_dict ]
                parent_dict[ key ] = parent_list
                parent_dict = sub_dict

        return parent_list
```

And one test for dict maker

```py
class MyTestCase( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_run( self ):
        input_ = [
            {
                'categories.id': 1,
                'categories.label': 'Computers',
                'categories.groups.id': 18,
                'categories.groups.label': 'Servers and Servers equipment',
                'categories.groups.names.id': 48,
                'categories.groups.names.label': 'HP Memory'
            },
            {
                'categories.id': 1,
                'categories.label': 'Computers',
                'categories.groups.id': 18,
                'categories.groups.label': 'Servers and Servers equipment',
                'categories.groups.names.id': 73,
                'categories.groups.names.label': 'HP Options for servers'
            },
        ]
        expected = {
            'categories': [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'label': 'Computers',
                    'groups': [
                        {
                            'id': 18,
                            'label': 'Servers and Servers equipment',
                            'names': [
                                {
                                    'id': 48,
                                    'label': 'HP Memory'
                                },
                                {
                                    'id': 73,
                                    'label': 'HP Options for servers'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            'id': 84,
                            'label': 'Tablets',
                            'names': [
                                {
                                    'id': 310,
                                    'label': 'Tablets Samsung'
                                },
                                {
                                    'id': 313,
                                    'label': 'Tablets Sony'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }

    maker = DictMaker( input_ )
    actual = maker.dict()

    self.assertEqual( actual, expected )
```

In online it works fine (perhaps due to PyPy). But local run is strange.
python (3.4.3)

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: code in reference http://ideone.com/sPFNOJ

Comment: please post your code within the body of the question, not a link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

FIX. this is due to dict keys order is undefined when iterating.
To solve problem add force sort.

```
def _make( self ):
    for item in self._input:
        for long_key, val in item.items( ):
            self._add_leaf_value( long_key, val )
```

change to

```
def _make( self ):
    for item in self._input:
        items = list( item.items( ) )
        items.sort( key=lambda t: len( t[ 0 ] ) )
        for long_key, val in items:
            self._add_leaf_value( long_key, val )
```